# Argument conversion: (normal) pointer to void pointer, cast needed?

Tags: c, pointers, argument-passing

When assigning to or from a `void`-pointer no cast is needed (C99 §6.3.2.2 sub 1 / §6.5.16.1 sub 1). Is this also true when passing a (for example `int`-)pointer to a function that expects a `void`-pointer?

For example:

```
void foo(void * p){
    // Do something
}

int main(){
    int i = 12;
    foo(&i); // int * to void *: no cast needed?
}
```

When I compile this with GCC (4.8.1, MinGW-32) I get neither errors nor warnings (with `-Wall` & `-pedantic`).

In contrast [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433566/249237) it is suggested that a cast is needed for this call (to eliminate `-Wformat` warnings):

```
int main(){
    int i = 12;
    printf("%p\n", &i);
}
```

But in my case GCC doesn't complain.

So: are casts needed when passing a non-`void`-pointer to a function that expects a `void`-pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is `printf` is a variadic function and variadic functions follow different conversion rules on their trailing arguments.

```
foo(&i);
```

no cast is needed here as `foo` is a prototyped function. C says `&i` is converted to the type of `p` as if by assignment and in C there is an implicit between all object pointer types to `void *`.

The case with `printf` is different as variadic functions like `printf` have default argument promotions on their remaining arguments and no conversion occur on the argument of pointer types.

C on prototyped functions:

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p7) "If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as      if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type."

C on variadic functions:

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p7) "(C99, 6.5.2.2p7) "The ellipsis notation in a function            prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default  argument promotions are performed on trailing
>   arguments."

*So: are casts needed when passing a non-void-pointer to a function that expects a void-pointer?*

For `printf`, `p` conversion specifier requires a `void *` argument. If the argument is of a different type, the function call invokes undefined behavior. So if the argument of `p` is an object pointer type, the `(void *)` cast is required.

> (C99, 7.19.6.1p8) "p The argument shall be a pointer to void."

Comment: You seem to have quoted the same sentence on both "C on prototyped functions" and ".. variadic ..", I assume you mean the second part of paragraph 7? *"The ellipsis notation.."*

Comment: You stopped quoting before the relevant part for calls to variadic functions: "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments". And promotions are only performed for integer types and float, not for pointers.

Comment: Yes, I pasted two times the same paragraph by mistake as I had to leave. Now, I'm away, will fix it when back. Or if anyone wants to fix my answer, he's welcome:)

Comment: What does it mean by trailing arguments?

Comment: @haccks the trailing arguments are the arguments that relate to the ellipsis notation (the `...` in `printf` prototype).

Comment: Since people seem to be quoting your answer as though it's authoritarian, and don't get me wrong, you are a very knowledgeable person... but I think you should cite [6.2.5p28](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) and it's footnote, which states that `char *` (and other "pointer to character" types) are interchangeable as arguments of type `void *`; no conversion is necessary...

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor I actually didn't quote it on purpose. C says `void *` and `char *` (and other pointers to character variants) have the same representation and alignment. For this reason I know a lot of C experts that argue that omitting the cast for example in `char *p = ...*; printf("%p\n", p);` is valid.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor My opinion is although the (non-normative) footnote of your quote says this implies interchangeability, the C Standard is also very clear with the `p` conversion specifier that the *argument shall be a pointer to void*.  I think it's a grey zone in the Standard and I'd love to see a DR that clarify it.